# Convolution using the basic definition/integration

Tags: integration, convolution

I am trying to find out the convolution of the following two functions using integration but I got stuck. Please help!

Consider the following functions on $\mathbb R^n$:

$$f(x) =  e^{-a|x|^2}, \ \ \ \ \ g(x) = e^{-b|x|^2}.$$

I am trying to find $f \ast g$ using the basic definition of the convolution:

$$(f \ast g ) (x) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(y)g(x-y) dy $$

My try : I tried to write the $|x|^2$ as a sum of its sqaured components and did similarly for the $|y|^2 $ but I am struggling with how to integrate the product i receive after doing this in side the integral.

Comment: Where do you get stuck?

Comment: One strategy is to write $|x|^2 = x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2$. Then combine $f(y)$ and $g(x-y)$ into one exponential, and complete the square in $y$.

Comment: Indeed, you have to use the basic definition. Why did you stop? Write $x=(x_1, \dots , x_n)$ and similarly $y= (y_1, \dots , y_n)$.